# Starting a views list from the nth element

Tags: 7, views

I have two views blocks. One displays the latest news item. I would like the other block to list 4 next latest news items starting from the second latest (as I have already displayed the first one).

Can I achieve this via the view's admin interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, Under pager settings, offset first four items. Click on the number of items to get this option

[image]

and on the page option settings change the offset.

[image]

Comment: second block needs to be override

Comment: For the sake of correct information: the offset number is 1, as the first block displays one item, not 4.